# Angular 8 - Is there a way to bind to a video element to determine when it is loaded/starts playing?

Tags: html, angular, angular8

Given:

```
<video poster="assets/videos/poster.png"
       #videoPlayer 
       onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
     <source src="assets/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And in Angular:

```
...

public videoLoaded: boolean = false;

...
```

How can I bind videoLoaded to update once the video starts playing? (or is loaded) I've looked online and saw some older jquery implementations that seem to not be working in newer versions of chrome and want to know the latest way on how to accomplish this

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is make a reference to the video player itself with Angular's `ViewChild` and check if it's clicked.

```js
@ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoPlayer: ElementRef;

videoClicked = false;

startVideo(): void {
    this.videoClicked = true;
    this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.play();
}
```

The `startVideo()` method will be used inside the HTML to trigger the change. The additional paragraph is used to see the change.

```html
<video (click)="startVideo()" width="400"
       #videoPlayer>
     <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p>Video clicked: {{videoClicked}}</p>
```

See [this StackBlitz as an example of above behaviour](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s2nyk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

**Edit**
A better way to do this is to use `HTMLMediaElement`'s `onplaying` and `loadeddata` event. See MDN for [documentation on onplaying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event) and [documentation on loadeddata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event). In normal JavaScript it would look like this:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.onplaying = (event) => {
  console.log('Video is no longer paused.');
};
```

In Angular, there are some small changes required. The HTML can stay pretty clean.

```html
<video controls width="400"
       #videoPlayer>
     <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p>Video loaded: {{dataLoaded}}</p>
<p>Video started: {{videoStarted}}</p>
```

The biggest changes are in the component, `ngAfterViewInit` checks if the element is there after view has been initialised. The `loadeddata` event is fired when the frame at the current playback position of the media has finished loading (so ready to play). Next to that, you can access the element's `onplaying` event to check if the video is not paused.

```js
@ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoPlayer: ElementRef;

dataLoaded = false;
videoStarted = false;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.onloadeddata = (event) => {
        console.log('Video data is loaded.');
        this.dataLoaded = true;
    };

    this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.onplaying = (event) => {
        console.log('Video is no longer paused.');
        this.videoStarted = true;
    };
}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz example to show this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cj8khg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: This is a home background video that acts as a background overlay. I'm guessing for this to work Il have to programatically click the video. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: Ya this is great. Works perfectly

Comment: Hi, any chance I can access a property from the progress event? Your reply was a valuable hint, however I would like to be able to extract the loaded and total properties, for big videos.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent

Comment: @ionescu77 Good question. Please ask a separate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML Audio/Video Events provided by html 5 video attribute.

loadeddata ->   Fires when the browser has loaded the current frame of the audio/video

loadedmetadata ->   Fires when the browser has loaded meta data for the audio/video

loadstart ->    Fires when the browser starts looking for the audio/video